# Cairo Dock can not update!

Tags: cairo-dock

I have installed Cairo Dock **Installed version: 3.0.0.1-0ubuntu1.1**

On the update Manager its showing update avilable as **Available version: 3.0.2-1ubuntu0~precise**

But when I click Install Updates its show Me attached image![image: Showing Me like this!]

So What I have to do if I Have Update Cairo Dock to the latest version?

Answer (score 1):

Try installing i.e upgrading it from terminal. Open a terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+T keyboard combo and use these commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cairo-dock
```

This will solve your problem.