# How to Remove Cairo Dock from Start Up?

Tags: startup-applications, cairo-dock

I have Cairo Dock's Version ***3.0.0.1*** installed and I've added it on start up. Now I want to remove it from Start Up, How I can do the Same? Please Help Me!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*(Assuming you are using 12.04)*

1. Click on the little wrench icon at the top-right position of the panel.
2. Select *Startup Applications*
3. There should be an entry for "Cairo-dock", select it
4. Remove the tick mark from the entry.

Logout and Login again to test it.

Comment: Thank You Very Much for Responding and Answering this, My Problem is solved! :)

Comment: @Gaurav sorry. i noticed it later. thanks and glad to help.

Comment: Can U answer My Another Question I asked?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/186927/cairo-dock-can-not-update

Answer (score 6):

- Run `Startup Applications` program

[image]

- Find an item that start with "GLX-Dock" in the shown list and unchecked it.

[image]

In your next login `Cairo Dock` will not start at login time.

Comment: Thank You Very Much for responding and for this solution! :) I clicked Gear icon from Panel and opened Startup Applications because on My Dash No Program is showing as "Startup Application", I disabled Cairo Dock from Startup Applications by clicking Gear icon and launching the same!