# How to remove cario-dock from startup?

Tags: 17.10

I want to remove Cario-dock from startup. I followed [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/187391/how-to-remove-cairo-dock-from-start-up) solution, and I removed Cario-dock application in Ubuntu Software Center. Cario-dock is not in the startup applications list bur it still is in the startup lage. How can I remove it?